# XSLT Choose - Trying to hide variable if empty

Tags: variables, xslt, hide

I have created this variable in XSLT:

I want to hide it if the user does not enter content into the CMS. I have added a CHOOSE statement to the XSLT, but found out that I can't use 'style' on a variable. I'm new to XSLT.

Code below...

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>
               <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not($thirdBlogPost)"> 
                         <xsl:variable name="thirdBlogPost" style="display:none"/>
                         <!--Use of 'style' on a variable isn't allowed-->
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise> <!--parameter has been supplied --> </xsl:otherwise>
          <td><img src="images/{$thirdBlogPost/@Image}" class="blog-front-image" /></td>
          <td>
               <h1><xsl:value-of select="$thirdBlogPost/@Title"/></h1>
               <xsl:value-of select="$thirdBlogPost/@Abstract" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>  
               <br />
               <a href="{$thirdBlogPost/@URL}">Read more...</a>
          </td>
               </xsl:choose>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT tags are processed by whatever you are using to do the XSLT transform -- they don't show up as part of the HTML (they are not displayed).
So there should be no need for the *style* attribute -- the variable will not be visible on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `xsl:variable` is

`<xsl:variable
  name = QName
  select = Expression
</xsl:variable>`

So, if you're trying define a variable with the value `display:none`, you'd write (note since the attribute contains a literal string, the string must be within quotes):

`<xsl:variable
  name = "thirdBlogPost"
  select = "'display:none'"
</xsl:variable>`

You could use the value like this:

```
<div style="{$thirdBlogPost}">this won't display</div>
```